# Como implementar uma regra de validação no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Gostaria de saber como validar uma regra no formulário do Auth.

No caso, é uma regra de CPF. **As regras de validação e mensagens de erro eu já tenho, mas não sei como implementar no framework.**

Devo colocar as regras direto no Validator do Controller?

Answer (score 2):

Eu não conheço nenhuma forma nativa do laravel para fazer está validação, já trabalhei em um projeto onde eu precisei validar cpf e telefone e a maneira foi utilizar uma biblioteca que está disponivel no github no seguinte link:

https://github.com/LaravelLegends/pt-br-validator

Você pode instalar via composer adicionando:

```
{
    "laravellegends/pt-br-validator" : "5.1.*"
}
```

No link citado a cima tem todas as dicas de como utilizar a biblioteca!

Comment: Obrigado por citar a minha biblioteca :)

Answer (score 0):

Indico o seguinte repositório para ser instalado em seu projeto Laravel:

https://github.com/geekcom/validator-docs

- A principal vantagem deste projeto em específico, que você pode validar o CPF ou CNPJ no mesmo campo. Segue:

  $this->validate($request, [
        'cpf_or_cnpj' => 'formato_cpf_cnpj|cpf_cnpj',
  ]);
- Documentação excelente.