# Regex para números repetidos no CNPJ

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, regex

Eu tenho a seguinte expressão regular:

```
regex:/^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\\-\d{2}$/
```

Eu consigo validar por isso, mas não para números repetidos.

Quero aplicar dentro dessa regex, uma forma que não aceite valores repetidos, por exemplo:
`11.111.111/1111-11`, `22.222.222/2222-22` assim por diante.

Estou usando essa Regex dentro de uma Request do Laravel.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'                  =>  'required:unique:companies',
            'email'                 =>  'required|email|unique:companies',
            'cnpj'                  =>  'required|unique:companies|regex:/^\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\\-\d{2}$/',
            'display_name'          =>  'required',
            'description'           =>  'string',
            'address'               =>  'required|string',
            'address_number'        =>  'required|numeric',
            'district'              =>  'required',
            'zip_code'              =>  'required|min:9',
            'city_id'               =>  'required',
            'site_url'              =>  'required',
            'photo_url'             =>  'required|image',
            'phone_number'          =>  'required|min:10',
        ];
    }
```

Como faria isso?

Comment: Indico o seguinte repositório para ser instalado em seu projeto Laravel: https://github.com/geekcom/validator-docs - A principal vantagem deste projeto em específico, que você pode validar o CPF ou CNPJ no mesmo campo. Segue: `$this->validate($request, [ 'cpf_or_cnpj' => 'formato_cpf_cnpj|cpf_cnpj', ]);` * Documentação excelente. Fonte: [Como implementar uma regra de validação no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235801/como-implementar-uma-regra-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel)

Comment: É, eu vi ele, pessoal recomendou ele aqui, estava vendo ele, ele é ótimo para isso, e ainda é bem fácil de usar dentro da aplicação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Resposta curta

```
^(?!(\d)\1\.\1{3}\.\1{3}\/\1{4}-\1{2}$)\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}$
```

Não tenho certeza se o hífen precisa estar escapado com `\\`, como você fez. Caso precise, basta mudar a regex para:

```
^(?!(\d)\1\.\1{3}\.\1{3}\/\1{4}\\-\1{2}$)\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/\d{4}\\-\d{2}$
```

### Resposta longa

Primeiro temos os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Com isso eu garanto que toda a string tem somente o que está dentro da regex.

Depois do `^` (início da string), a regex tem 2 partes principais. Vamos ver separadamente como cada uma funciona.

---

O primeiro trecho entre parênteses `(?!...)` é um [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Basicamente, ele verifica se a string **não corresponde** à expressão que está dentro dos parênteses.

A primeira coisa que temos no *lookahead* é `(\d)`. O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` corresponde aos dígitos, e [os parênteses formam um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Isso quer dizer que se o primeiro caractere for um dígito, ele será "capturado" pela regex. E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, ele será referenciado como o grupo 1 (o *lookahead* não conta pois ele por si só não forma um grupo de captura).

Em seguida eu uso `\1`, que é uma maneira de referenciar o grupo 1. Isso quer dizer que `\1` terá o mesmo valor do dígito que foi capturado no grupo 1. Ou seja, `(\d)\1` verifica se há dois dígitos seguidos e se eles são o mesmo dígito.

Em seguida temos `\.`, que corresponde ao próprio caractere ponto (`.`), e depois temos `\1{3}`, que significa "exatamente 3 ocorrências (`{3}`) do que foi capturado no grupo 1 (ou seja, o dígito que capturamos em `(\d)`)".

O restante da expressão (`\.\1{3}\/\1{4}-\1{2}$`) verifica se tem outro ponto, mais 3 ocorrências do mesmo dígito, barra, 4 ocorrências do mesmo dígito, hífen e 2 ocorrências do mesmo dígito, e por fim o final da string (`$`).

Ou seja, a expressão inteira verifica se o mesmo dígito se repete (ela corresponde a casos como `11.111.111/1111-11` e `22.222.222/2222-22`). E o *negative lookahead* (`(?!...)`) garante que a string **não** tem esse formato. Portanto, se todos os dígitos forem iguais, o *lookahead* falha e a regex não encontra um *match*.

O truque do *lookahead* é que primeiro ele verifica a string e caso esteja ok, ele **volta para onde estava** e continua avaliando o restante da expressão. Como o *lookahead* está logo depois do `^` (início da string), quer dizer que ele volta para o início da string e continua avaliando o restante da regex. Se o *lookahead* falhar, a regex também falha e não encontra nenhum *match*.

---

A segunda parte é a regex que você já estava usando (2 dígitos, ponto, 3 dígitos, ponto, 3 dígitos, barra, 4 dígitos, hífen, 2 dígitos e final da string).

A combinação do *lookahead* com a sua expressão garante que você tem o que precisa:

- o *negative lookahead* garante que os dígitos não são todos iguais
- se a verificação do *lookahead* deu certo (ou seja, não cai nos casos em que todos os dígitos são iguais), ele volta para onde estava (no caso, o início da string) e verifica o restante da expressão
- o restante verifica se está no formato que você especificou

Comment: Eu tinha visto agora a pouco sobre esse `\1`

Comment: @RomuloSousa Sim, é muito útil para casos como esse, em que você precisa verificar se um mesmo valor se repete

Comment: Eu sei um pouco de regex, mas ele é bem útil para várias coisas, mas sua explicação é muito boa.

Comment: quando eu tento cadastrar, me aparece esse erro.
`No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: Vou confessar que não entendo muito sobre o Laravel, mas em uma pesquisa rápida achei [este](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/954594) e [este](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/954594) link. Faltou colocar a `/` antes e depois (ela é um delimitador que algumas linguagens usam, para dizer que tudo que está dentro dele é uma regex, mas não faz parte da regex em si).

Comment: Deu certo, era as aspas `" "` que estava faltando.

Comment: Valeu cara! Muito obrigado!