# Validação telefone C#

Tags: c#

A tempos atrás pesquisei aqui validação para o número de telefone que aceitava somente o tipo do formato `(11) 98162-7844` ou `(11) 8162-7844`, porém não localizei uma validação para o número "existente" ou não sequêncial, ex:

```
(11) 9999-9999
(99) 9999-9999
(12) 1212-1212
```

alguma ideia?

```
public static void Main()
{

    string Numero = "(11) 99999-9999";

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\([0-9]{2}\))\s([9]{1})?([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})$");
    Match match = regex.Match(Numero);

    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Este telefone é válido");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Número inválido");
}
```

Comment: Eu escrevo que pesquisei e mesmo assim sempre tem kkk Cara você testou o código desse post ai? bota um Telefone (99) 9999-9999 vai dar telefone válido, se você me provar que existe esse telefone, então podemos considerar duplicada.

Comment: Desculpe, não tinha prestado atenção no "número existente". A regex só verifica o formato, pra saber se um telefone existe mesmo, só consultando serviços específicos (que talvez as operadores ou a Anatel disponibilizem, mas aí eu já não sei). Claro que vc pode mudar a regex para só ter DDD's válidos (`(11|14|15|...)`), mas para saber se o número existe não tem como só com regex...

Comment: E a regra para número sequencial tem que ser muito bem definida para não excluir números válidos. Por exemplo, 98765-1234 não pode ser válido? Se bobear existem números assim - não liguei para testar :-) mas nada impede que existam tais números... O que *poderia* ter é uma regra mais simples, como todos os dígitos iguais (ou "a maioria igual", sendo que definir o valor de "maioria" também é arbitrário). Enfim, é isso, só com regex talvez não dê para fazer o que vc quer (a menos que vc crie alguns critérios arbitrários mais simplificados)

Comment: Acho que é mais simples do que isso, precisamos seria sequencial, pode ser até ddd 11 porém não posso aceitar numero 9999-9999 ou 8888-888 ou 1234-5678

Comment: @Voltz mas estes são números válidos. Não faz sentido bloquear. Está querendo resolver o problema da maneira errada, é um caso de [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). A única regra para celular no brasil é  1o dígito ser 9.

Comment: Como assim válido? 11 99999-9999 isso é valido?

Comment: Perfeitamente, por qual motivo não seria? O de um atual colega de trabalho é 19 9 9999-9*** (omiti os 3 ultimos digitos por questao de privacidade, e tb tem repetição neles - mas poderia terminar em 999 sem problema nenhum) - Se quer validar um telefone, mande um SMS (ou robocall para fixos) e faça o usuário confirmar o código recebido (é o que eu faço em alguns sistemas).

Comment: Pra evitar números repetidos, dá pra adaptar [essa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340489/112052) (mudando o formato para telefone, obviamente - mas como o Bacco disse, ainda pode ser válido), mas para verificar sequencial é mais fácil não usar regex. Expressões regulares trabalham com texto (mesmo `9` é tratado como o caractere correspondente ao dígito 9, não o valor numérico em si) e verificar se o próximo é igual ao "anterior + 1" é muito mais fácil de fazer com uma linguagem de programação e as respectivas funções de string e números, do que com regex :-)

Comment: Voltz inclusive esse mesmo que vc passou  por último (11) 9999...... existe e funciona, pelo jeito faltou vc testar (coitado do dono agora...)

Comment: @Bacco Eu até pensei em fazer esse teste, mas fiquei com receio de realmente existir o número :-)

Comment: Nesse [link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano_de_numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o) têm as regras de formatação para os números de telefone brasileiros.